# Is it safe putting a Task, with scoped service dependencies, in a Singleton queue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am pretty much using the example provided in Microsoft docs for [queuing background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks).

In this queue I am adding a `Func<Task>`, to be executed later by `QueuedHostedService`.

Controller - HTTP POST

```
...
Func<Task> workItem = () => _mockService.DoWorkAsync(guid);
_queue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(workItem);
return Ok();
```

MockService.DoWorkAsync

```
var data = await _insideMockService.GetAsync();
await _anotherService.Notify(data);
```

BackgroundTaskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem

```
private ConcurrentQueue<Func<Task>> _workItems
private SemaphoreSlim _signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<Task> workItem)
{
    if (workItem == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
    }
    _workItems.Enqueue(workItem);
    _signal.Release();
}
```

QueuedHostedService.ExecuteAsync

```
_currentTask = await _queue.DequeueAsync(cancellationToken);
try
{
    await _currentTask();
...
```

BackgroundTaskQueue.DequeueAsync

```
public async Task<Func<Task>> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _signal.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
    _workItemsById.TryDequeue(out var workItem);
    return workItem;
}
```

Startup.ConfigureServices

```
services.AddScoped<IMockService, MockService>(); // Implements DoWorkAsync
services.AddScoped<IInsideMockService, InsideMockService>(); // DoWorkAsync requires this dependency 
services.AddScoped<IAnotherService, AnotherService>(); // DoWorkAsync requires this dependency 
services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();
services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue>();
```

`IMockService.DoWorkAsync` method use `scoped` services. Ref to this method is added to a queue which resides in a `singleton` service. This queue is later read by a `HostedService` which is also a `singleton`.

Is there any chance that the service-references in `DoWorkAsync` will be disposed before being handled by `HostedService`? If we exclude the scenarios that the application is gracefully(or ungracefully) shut down.

Some local testruns with maybe a hundred requests (and some added `Task.Delay` in `DoWorkAsync`) seems to be working fine but I'm not sure if I'm missing something..

Comment: Given the nature of how scoped lifetime is treated, **YES** there is a chance, but it will depend on weather the request goes out of scope before the queued task has had time to be invoked.

Comment: Yes. Think about it logically. The whole point of queuing work is to run it later outside the scope of the current request/response cycle. If you're depending on services that only exist within that scope, then the operation will fail when the queue eventually starts it.

Comment: I'm not so sure in this case, if the scoped services would be disposed as soon as request finishes then it would be easy to reproduce an error. 
Just create a Controller method that puts a Func<Task> in queue and return immediately with a 200 OK. Let the Task have a delay of some seconds and fire of a bunch of requests. 
Which I have done successfully (as stated in last sentence of my question). The `HostedService` has no problem executing the tasks minutes after finished requests.

Comment: I'll edit question to enhance the fact that it returns immediately.

Comment: Do `MockService`, `InsideMockService` and `AnotherService` used in your "local tesruns with hundred requests" implements `IDisposable` _correctly_ (with throwing ObjectDisposedException)?

Comment: No, they are not implementing `IDisposable `.

Comment: That would probably explain why the references are alive even though their scope is not. They should however be handled by the GC when the object containing services (the `Func<Task>>` reference) is garbage collected, right? Since we are not dealing with connections or lots of memory allocation, is this really a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is not that reference to Func will be garbade-collected.

Problem is that any scoped service it use can be disposed.

When requests finishes, scope is disposed with all his disposable content. If your services will implement IDisposable - they will be disposed too. And your queued task will try to call disposed service(s) and fail.

And even if your service will not implement IDisposable itself - it may use, directly or indirectly, some other IDisposable object that *will* be disposed (for example, DbContext).

To make sure this stuff will not fail at some day - you should carefully control all objects/services (and their sub-objects/sub-services) used during `DoWorkAsync`. In this case - why not you register MockService istelf as singleton? :)

Correct way for background task is to capture `IServiceScopeFactory` instance, and call CreateScope() before any real job, and obtain any scoped services from it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Using ```IServiceScopeFactory ``` makes the most sense in the upcoming application.